# Jquery - Can I undo event on previous element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to ask, if possible to undo action on previous element which fired some event.

To illustrate my question we may use:

**HTML :**

```
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('ok');
  // looking a way to manipulate previous <a> which fired event, before i will add class to $(this)
});
```

If I click first `<a>` it will add ok class. And all I want to remove this class from `<a>` on clicking second `<a>`.

So I click first `<a>` and it has ok class. Next I click second `<a>` and second `<a>` has now ok class but not first one (I called this action Undo).

And is I click third `<a>`, previous clicked `<a>` should not have ok class. I hope it's clear.

Comment: Thanks for every post. Every post has nice technigues to archive my goal.
I was wondering if JQuery has any mechanism, which holds "prevent element" which fired event and is avaliable in Event object, but i see nothing usefull in documentation....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the following line after you add the class,

```
$("a").not(this).removeClass("ok");
```

so finally your click event function should look like,

```
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('ok');
  $("a").not(this).removeClass("ok");
});
```

it will add ok class on the clicked item, and then remove ok class from any 'a' which is not the clicked one.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the class on the sibling elements

```js
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('ok').siblings().removeClass('ok')
});
```

```css
a {display: block}
.ok {color : red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">First</a>
<a href="#">Second</a>
<a href="#">Third</a>
<a href="#">Fourth</a>
```

Comment: Gotta love those one-liners

Answer (score 3):

Just add :

```
$('a.ok').removeClass('ok'); //if you have 'a' with class 'ok' just in this part of page
//OR 
$(this).siblings().removeClass('ok');
```

Before :

```
$(this).addClass('ok');
```

So it will remove the class `ok` from all `a` tags then add it to the clicked one.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('ok');
  $(this).addClass('ok');
});
```

```css
.ok{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
<a href="#">4</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

for your example you can do somthing like this:

```
 $('a').on('click',function(e) {
      $('a.ok').removeClass('ok'); // this will remove ok class from all a
      $(this).addClass('ok');
     // looking a way to manipulate previous <a> which fired event, before i      will add class to $(this)
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the Way to remove .ok class from previously clicked element

```
var prev_a = '';
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('ok');
  $(prev_a).removeClass('ok');
  prev_a = this;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class to all the links that may be clicked and then do the following:

```js
var anchors = $('a.test'); // cache the links for better performance

anchors.on('click',function(e) {
  anchors.removeClass('ok'); // remove the class from all anchors
  $(this).addClass('ok');    // add the class to this anchor
});
```

```css
.ok {color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="test">test 1</a>
<a href="#" class="test">test 2</a>
<a href="#" class="test">test 3</a>
<a href="#" class="test">test 4</a>
```